# How to use SQlite NULL inside function default parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, select, where-clause

Id like to get domains from sqlite database where ip is NULL. I also want to make function so I can get domains with specific IPs in the future. I wrote function like this:

```
def get_domains(self, ip=None):
    """gets all the domains from domain table

    Keyword Arguments:
        ip {str} -- IP of the domain (default: {None})

    Returns:
        sqlite3.Row -- rows of the selected domains
    """
    sql = "SELECT domain FROM domains WHERE ip = ?"
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql, (ip,))
        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return rows
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

but it returns no rows. It works when I test with other values, but can't make it to read WHERE ip = null.
How do I return rows where default ip is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check for nullness with the equality operator; for this you need special expression `IS NULL`. Some databases offer a null-safe operator for equality (typically, MySQL has `<=>`, Postgres supports the standard `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`). SQLite offers `IS` for that.

```
SELECT domain FROM domains WHERE ip IS ?
```

Comment: It works. Does this means that we should do one or both of this: 1. avoid NULL in sqlite and use proper value; 2. avoid "WHERE ip =" and always use "WHERE ip IS" no matter what.?